# java how to find my unknown brother? (2 classes implementing same interface)

Tags: java, reflection, interface

i have the following situation:

i am a class numberOneUser and a framework loads me as a .class file from the file system at runtime.

i know that in the directory where my .class file lies there are more .class files.
(eg theOtherUser.class)

some of them implement the same interface as i do. (called User)

now i want to find at runtime the secound (or more) class(es) that implement that interface and modify them with reflection (eg override methods).

the only reference i have to the framework is that i know that i am being called and given a reference to a object that i can respond do which is part of the framework.
furthermore i know that the framework lies as framework.jar file in the directory above me.

no additional information is available.

how to find this other classes?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) may its helps you.

```
Set<Class<? extends YourClassOrInterface>> subTypes = 
 reflections.getSubTypesOf(YourClassOrInterface.class);
```

Comment: hey @Sumit Singh do you know how this library collects all subtypes?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322600/181336) which addresses how to find .class files in a directory and create a collection of Class elements. Once you have the classes you could use reflection or the instanceof operator to determine which ones implement your interface.